# How to get the text and Image properties of custom button?

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

I created a custom button which is inherited from Button class.The button should be contain following things,

It should be fixed size.(I completed this, it working fine)
**Based on control size align the Text and image to the control.
I need to use this control for multiple application.** Based on application user
give a text and image values for the button.

C#

```
Here, there is four constructor,


public customButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains Text property only.
        /// call the base constructor with Image is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public customButton(string text)
        {
            //customButton(text, null);
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains Image property only.
        /// call the base constructor with text is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="icon"></param>
        public customButton(Image icon)
        {
            //customButton(null, icon); //How to call the constructor 
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains both image and text values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        /// <param name="icon"></param>
        public customButton(string text, Image icon)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (icon != null)
            {
                iconAvailable = true;
                this.Image = icon; //Here I Need to get the icon value here,                }
            if (text != string.Empty || text != null)
            {
                textAvailable = true;
                this.Text = text;// // Here Need to get the text value here, Not completed
            }

            //align icon and text on booleans
            setControlAlignment();
        }
```

How can I get the text and image value of button, based on the value will call the constructor.

Edit:

If button contains only text, Text should be in middle center, if button contains only image, image should be in middle center. So **I need to check the availability of text and image based on that I need to call the constructor.** How to get the image and text value? in constructor call

Answer (score 0):

There is a special syntax to do this. The calls to `InitializeComponent` needed to be removed from the specialized contructors, otherwise it would be called twice:

```
        public customButton() : this(null, null)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains Text property only.
        /// call the base constructor with Image is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public customButton(string text) : this(text, null)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains Image property only.
        /// call the base constructor with text is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="icon"></param>
        public customButton(Image icon) : this(null, icon)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will call when button contains both image and text values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        /// <param name="icon"></param>
        public customButton(string text, Image icon)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (icon != null)
            {
                iconAvailable = true;
                this.Image = icon; //Here I Need to get the icon value here,                }
            if (text != string.Empty || text != null)
            {
                textAvailable = true;
                this.Text = text;// // Here Need to get the text value here, Not completed
            }

            //align icon and text on booleans
            setControlAlignment();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I need a text and icon value. How to get that? Based on the image and text value I will align the text and image in to button control

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand what you mean. You will pass those values when instantiating the `customButton` (I would recommend renaming to `CustomButton`) like this `customButton btn = new customButton("Button Text", Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.png"));`. In this example the image is loaded from a file, but it could also be a resource or drawn programatically or loaded from a remote source.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create private variables to store the value that you pass into the constructor, then you can use them later on...

i.e.

```
    private string _text;
private Image _icon;

public customButton() : this(null, null)
    {
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor will call when button contains Text property only.
    /// call the base constructor with Image is null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    public customButton(string text) : this(text, null)
    {

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor will call when button contains Image property only.
    /// call the base constructor with text is null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    public customButton(Image icon) : this(null, icon)
    {

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor will call when button contains both image and text values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    public customButton(string text, Image icon)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    _text = this.text;
        _icon = this.icon;

        if (icon != null)
        {
            iconAvailable = true;
            this.Image = this.icon; //Here I Need to get the icon value here,                }
        if (text != string.Empty || this.text != null)
        {
            textAvailable = true;
            this.Text = this.text;// // Here Need to get the text value here, Not completed
        }

        //align icon and text on booleans
        setControlAlignment(this.text, this.icon);
    }

    private void setControlAlignment(string text, Image icon);
    {
       HorizontalAlignment textPos;
       HorizontalAlignment iconPos;

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) && this.icon != null)       // If we have both text and icon values
       {
    textPos = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            iconPos = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
       }
   else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.text) && this.icon != null)
   {
    iconPos = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
       }
   else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.text) && this.icon == null)
   {
    textPos = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
       }

   // and whatever else you want to do...
    }
```

The lines:
this.Image = this.icon; //Here I Need to get the icon value here,
and
this.Text = this.text;// // Here Need to get the text value here, Not completed

Should already be working as "text" and "icon" will be set to the values passed in.

public customButton(string text, Image icon) 
is being called by all constructors, so I only need to set _text and _icon once if you want to access them in other methods elsewhere in your code.

You could do the same for position if you wanted i.e. make _textPos and _iconPos  global if you need to access these variables elsewhere (currently defined in setControlAlignment).

The code doesn't make use of _text or _icon (assigned, but never used) - as I pass the values to the setControlAlignment method.  Since you haven't put the full code here, if you do need to access these values in other methods you could simply access _text or _icon.